# Desplegar aplicacion PHP sobre HTTPS en Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, aws, https, amazon

En mi empresa estamos utilizando por primera vez AWS Elastic Beanstalk para desplegar una aplicación. En este caso se trata de una aplicación de instancia simple creada en PHP con el framework CodeIgniter 3. Tenemos un entorno con la aplicación desplegada y funcionando, pero no logramos hacerlo funcionar por HTTPS.

Lo hemos desplegado con Apache como proxy y hemos generado los archivos de configuración que indican en su documentación y nos da error al desplegar la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estamos probando a intentar desplegar un "Hello World" de prueba con HTTPS, pero nos estamos volviendo locos.

Ahora mismo tenemos los siguientes archivos de configuración cargados en .ebextensions:

https-instance-single.config

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Y https-instance.config:

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod24_ssl : []

files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        SSLEngine             on
        SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
        SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
        SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder   On
        SSLSessionTickets     Off
        
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
        Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
        
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/ retry=0
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" early
      </VirtualHost>
  
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      Mi certificado
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      Mi clave privada
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Si cambiamos el paquete "mod24_ssl" a "mod_ssl" no da error al desplegar la aplicación, pero tampoco funciona HTTPS y si hacemos telnet en cualquiera de los dos casos al puerto 443, no aparece que esté abierto.

En el grupo de seguridad tenemos habilitado el tráfico de entrada para los puertos 80 y 443 desde cualquier origen.

Si alguien se ha encontrado con estos mismos problemas, por favor agradeceríamos mucho cualquier ayuda.

Un saludo